# Aplicación desplegada en la ruta de contexto, pero el contexto no pudo arrancar

Tags: java, html, jsp

Trabajo en una aplicación web con NetBeans pero me arroja el siguiente error: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Este es el archivo web.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Missael, debes revisar tu fichero `web.xml`, lo puedes mostrar? A parte de ello tambien revisar los logs del Tomcat para ver en detalle lo sucedido.

Comment: Hola Missael. Por favor selecciona el contenido de la pestaña que dice **Apache Tomcat or TomEE Log**. Allí indica el verdadero error que sucede con la aplicación.

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, edite la pregunta para mostrar lo que me piden. Gracias por la aclaracion Luiggi

Comment: Missael. Te recomiendo colocar el contenido en texto plano. Colocar imágenes dificulta el proceso. Además, el problema que tienes es porque no has definido el servlet correctamente.

Comment: SI, ya  corregí el error tienen razón el problema era el archivo web.xml Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en la definición del servlet. Debes definiri el servlet de la siguiente manera en el archivo web.xml:

```
<servlet-config>
    <servlet-name>autenticacion</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>el.paquete.de.tu.Clase</servlet-class>
</servlet-config>
```